# Can "number of terms of some polynomial that describes a function" be expressed in set-theoretic/logic way?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, polynomials

I would like to express "there exists a function that the number of terms of some polynomial that describes the function is smaller than some defined number" in set-theoretic/logic way (first-order sentence). Can this be done?

Also, can we say in first-order sentence that "there exists a function that every term is smaller than some defined number"?

(Clarification: By the number of terms, I mean: $f(x) = x^3+2x+2$ has three terms - $x^3, 2x, 2$.)

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a polynomial as an infinite sequence that has only finitely many non-zero entries.

The number of terms is the number of non-zero entries of such sequence.

Formally, if the polynomials are over the field $F$ (or ring, or whatever structure that can "hold" polynomials) then given a polynomial $f$ we identify it with the sequence $\langle f_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nx^n$. Such sequence $f$ is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $F$, and what are interested is the following: $$\left|f^{-1}(F\setminus\{0\})\right|$$

That is, the cardinality of the preimage of the non-zero elements. Or in other words "how many elements are mapped to a non-zero coefficient".

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

The space of polynomials is spanned by the monomials (the powers of $x$ in your notation). Define the 'number of terms' of a polynomial $p$ to be minimal amount of monomials such that their span contains $p$.

Comment: Yes, but how does one do this in set-theoretic language? First-order sentence, I mean.